# Kineticjs - Fixed fill pattern of shape being rotated

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I use [kineticjs](http://kineticjs.com) to work with shapes and transitions. For now I have made next code example:

http://jsfiddle.net/z6LaH/2/

```
hexagon = new Kinetic.RegularPolygon({
    x: stage.getWidth() / 2,
    y: stage.getHeight() / 2,
    sides: 6,
    radius: hexRadius,
    cornerRadius: 0,
    fillPatternImage: img,
    fillPatternOffset: [150, -150],
    //fill: 'white',
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 0
});

hexagon.on('mouseover touchstart', function() {
    this.transitionTo({
        cornerRadius: transRadius,
        rotation: Math.PI / 2,
        scale: {x: 0.75, y: 0.75},
        easing: 'ease-in',
        duration: duration,

        callback: function() {
            hexagon.transitionTo({
                scale: {x: 1.1, y: 1.1},
                duration: duration * 7,
                easing: 'elastic-ease-out'
            });
        }
    });
});
```

As you can see, fill pattern is rotating with shape. I need it to be fixed. So my question is:

**Is it posible to make fixed fill pattern, while shape is rotating, and how?**

---

UPDATE:

I got next approach: rotate fill pattern in opposite direction.

http://jsfiddle.net/z6LaH/3/

Is there any more elegant way to do the same?

Comment: Your edit was one way I could think of; another may be to use the shape as a mask and set the background element it's masking to have the fixed background image. I'm not that familiar with Kinetic.js, so I don't know if it can mask or not, or if that's possible at all in HTML/CSS...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eric has just added the ability to save a user-defined clipping function to layers and groups.

First, you define a function that draws a clipping region on a layer or group

```
var layer = new Kinetic.Layer({
    clipFunc: function(canvas) {
        var context = canvas.getContext();
        context.rect(0, 0, 400, 100);
    } 
});
```

Then you call the .clip() function to apply the clip.  Here is Kinetic’s clip() function in the source code:

```
_clip: function(container) {
   var context = this.getContext(); 
   context.save();
   this._applyAncestorTransforms(container);
   context.beginPath(); 
   container.getClipFunc()(this);
   context.clip();
   context.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
}
```

The clip() function applies existing transforms before doing the clip.  If you don’t like the transform part of the Kinetic function, you can always use “container.getClipFunc()” and then build your own myClipWithoutTransform() based on the _clip function above.